# Get Request displaying foreign key tables

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

When i don't have anything in my 'bookings' table my GET endpoints for my customer and Accommodation table work perfectly. Once i create a booking every get request for each table returns every entry in every table.
This is my data model

[image: DataModel]

This is my get request for customers

```
// GET: api/Customer
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCUSTOMERs()
    {
        var customers = await db.Customers.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(customers);
    }
```

When i call a get request for the customer table i only want customer data how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entity framework model has lazy loading enabled by default.

When you `return Ok(customers);` the API will attempt to serialize the entities so that they can be sent as (probably) JSON or XML. As it serializes through each customer entity it will encounter the `Bookings` property. As the serializer is requesting that property, Entity Framework will "lazy load" in the bookings which are associated with the customer. Then the serializer will attempt to serialize each booking and hit the `Accommodations` property... and so on.

Your code above is returning all customers, so you will end up returning every accommodation which has been booked. I expect if you made a new `Accommodation` which had no bookings, it would not be returned in the output from this call.

There are several ways you can prevent all this from happening:

**Disable Lazy Loading**
You can disable lazy loading on an EF model by opening the model, right click on the white background of the model diagram and choose "Properties", then set "Lazy Loading Enabled" to "False".
If you have other functions where you want to access the related properties from an entity, then you can either load them in to the context with an "Include" or load them separately and let the EF fixup join the entities together.

My personal opinion is that disabling lazy-loading is generally a good idea because it makes you think about the queries you are making to the database and you have to be much more explicit about asking for what data should be returned. However, it can be a lot more effort and is probably something to look at when you start trying to optimise your application rather than just getting it working.

This Microsoft page "[Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)" also explains various options (as well as describing exactly the issue with lazy loading your entire database!).

**Map Your Entities and Return DTOs**
You have more control about how the code traverses your model if you map the entities from EF into DTO's.
From an API perspective using DTOs is a great idea because it allows you to more or less define the output of an endpoint like an interface. This can often remain the same while the underlying data structure may change. Returning the output of an EF model means that if the model changes, things which use that data may also need to change.
Something like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) is often used to map an EF entity into DTOs.

**Serializer Settings**
There may be some media-type formatter settings which allow you to limit the depth of entities which will be traversed for serialisation. See [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) for a place to start.
This is probably too broad of a change, and when you want to actually return related objects would cause a problem there instead.